# prawcore.exceptions.OAuthException error even though I checked credentials

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, reddit, praw

I am getting a credential error but I am not understanding why. I feel as though I've triple checked that they are correct and also manually logged in. My code is shown below

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import praw
load_dotenv()

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id=os.getenv('reddit_personal_use'),
                     client_secret=os.getenv('reddit_api_key'),
                     user_agent=os.getenv('reddit_app_name'),
                     username=os.getenv('reddit_username'),
                     password=os.getenv('reddit_pw'))

print(reddit.user.me())
```

I saved my .env file in the root of the project directory and have it listed as

```
reddit_api_key=####
reddit_username=####
reddit_pw=####
reddit_app_name=some words here that explain my code, author /u/username
reddit_personal_use=###
```

Should I maybe be adding quotes to all the values for the key value pairs? When I run the print statement to check that the credentials went through OK I get:

> response, payload["error"], payload.get("error_description")
> prawcore.exceptions.OAuthException: invalid_grant error processing request

Should I be making any other changes that I may not be making?
Also in the Reddit API request there is a section for name. Should the name on the API request match the user_agent name? In examples I've seen online they never fully say if they should match, they just write that it should be unique and include your username. But I am confused what the name part in the request is then:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a series of unwritten/undocumented reddit api rules that you can only find on /r/redditdev. Per the [link](http://prawcore.exceptions.OAuthException:%20invalid_grant%20error%20processing%20request)

If your credentials are right, consider trying the following

1. Change your user agent to omit the word bot...
2. Add the bot name as a developer onto the application